# Does phabricator allow forking of projects

Tags: git, phabricator

As Currently GitHub and Bitbucket allow of forking of repository  and have tested on it . But in my case project is hosted on phabricator and it doesnot seem to have options for it.

Yesterday i had linked my  Bitbucket projects (origin and forked project) to phabricator  seperate repository. Now if code is pushed to bitbucket  changes are automatically reflected on phabricator .  But I don't want phabricator to have any dependency on bitbucket.  What if bitbucket projects got deleted , it will also be reflected on phabricator.

Is there any way to achieve forking of repository on phabricator available ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phabricator at the moment does not support forking. There is a [feature request](https://secure.phabricator.com/T10691) at their website for this, but it is not updated for a year now.